# Database diagramming tool for PostgreSQL

Tags: database-design, postgresql, diagram

Does anyone know of a plug-in for PostgreSQL's pgAdmin III that enables DB diagrams such as in SQL Server?

Comment: Not a plugin, rather you can use an independent Jar, to create the visualization, it's [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net). It's an awesome tool. I have posted [a step-by-step guide](http://kmonsoor.wordpress.com/2014/12/18/how-to-generate-er-diagram-from-postgresql-database/) to use it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It costs a little (you can try it though) but is v. easy to use and works a treat: http://www.datanamic.com/

Here is a list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools

Comment: I cam across this one: http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/postgresql/maestro

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows and got Visio installed you might try this [recipe](http://www.crystalballinc.com/vlad/index/27.html). I've noticed that some foreign key aren't generated for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this suits your needs http://pgmodeler.com.br/

I tried it by myself but unfortunately the version I tried half a year ago was very unstable on mac.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a plug-in exists. Check this post for some possible options.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115410/generate-er-diagram-from-postgres-sql-database-on-osx-snow-leopard